# PHP socket_accept throws warnings in non-blocking mode

Tags: php, sockets, networking

I want to create an easy PHP server (TCP-based) that would serve actual time and close the connection immediately. I've done that already. I wanted to add crtl-C handling so I needed to replace blocking socket_accept with non-blocking (this is because when the blocking socket_accept instruction is reached and I send SIGINT /ctrl-C/ then the server will still be alive until the first client is server and then it closes itself - and I didn't want this behavior).

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush();

if ($argc != 2)
    die("Wrong params");

$address = 'localhost';
$port = $argv[1];

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false)
    die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n");

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false)
    die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false)
    die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");

socket_set_nonblock($sock);

$remote_host = $remote_port = $msgsock = null;

declare(ticks = 1);

function sig_handler($signo)
{
    switch ($signo) {
        case SIGTERM:
        case SIGINT:
            global $sock;
            socket_shutdown($sock);
            socket_close($sock);
            echo "Terminating...\n";
            exit;
    }
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "sig_handler");

echo "Starting server\n";

while (1) {
    do {
        $msgsock = socket_accept($sock);
        usleep(100000);
    } while ($msgsock === false);

    socket_getpeername($msgsock, $remote_host, $remote_port);
    echo "Connection made from {$remote_host}:{$remote_port}\n";

    $msg = date('r', time()) . "\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));
    socket_close($msgsock);
};

socket_close($sock);
```

Everything works fine except for one detail... I get the following PHP warning every 0.1 second (= 100000 microseconds):

```
PHP Warning:  socket_accept(): unable to accept incoming connection [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable in /home/tomasz/Development/Python/twisted/time-server.php on line 55
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/tomasz/Development/Python/twisted/time-server.php:0
PHP   2. socket_accept() /home/tomasz/Development/Python/twisted/time-server.php:55
```

What I've tried to achieve is non-blocking accept: PHP uses the server socket, checks if there's any connection awaiting to be served. I not - wait 0.1 second. If there is a pending connection, serve it. All functionality is OK except that I've got no idea why is this warning thrown - I just want to check if there's any connection to be served. Modifying `error_reporting` to `E_ERROR` makes the warnings quiet, but I hope there's a better way to solve that...

---

edit:

modifying `socket_accept($sock)` to `@socket_accept($sock)` will just suspress warnings from  being thrown, but still this doesn't state why it is thrown...

Answer (score 1):

I located your question while searching for a solution to the exact same problem.  Additionally, I found a few other posts asking about the same thing, but also without solutions.  Some posts indicated that there was no way to prevent `socket_accept()` from throwing warnings, as it is by design to indicate "there is no waiting connection to accept."  I couldn't confirm this as it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the PHP manual page for [`socket_accept()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php)

Like you, I wasn't satisfied with using any sort of error suppression.  It seemed the next logical step was to wrap `socket_accept()` in some sort of conditional so that it would only execute if I knew there was a connection waiting.  I couldn't find anything that did this.  But when using `stream_*()` functions instead of just `socket_*()` functions, it looks like there is.  So I switched out to using streams (seems there are some other advantages as well), as follows:

```
if (( $socket = stream_socket_server( "tcp://$address:$port", $errno, $errstr )) === FALSE ) {
    die( "failed to create socket: $errstr\n" );
}

echo "Waiting for clients to connect...\n";

while ( $server_listening ) {
    $read  = array( $socket );
    $array = array();

    if ( stream_select( $read, $array, $array, 0 )) {
        $connection = stream_socket_accept( $socket, 0 );

        client_handler( $socket, $connection );
    } else {
        usleep( 100 );
    }
}
```

This seems to work well.  My script only attempts to accept the connection if it first determines that there is a connection waiting.  After going through this, I did find that there was an equivalent socket function for this, [`socket_select()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), which appears to work the same way.  So you may be able to do something similar if you wanted to stick with the `socket_*()` functions.

On a side note, I'm glad I made the switch to streams as they seem easier to work with.  And since my application is limited to TCP, I don't seem to be missing any functionality that I would get with more low-level sockets.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that does that, and it's select().  Nonblocking socket IO should use select(), period.   In PHP that means [socket_select()](https://www.php.net/socket-select). See any reference on BSD sockets for more info.